# Extracting Dictionary Values from a Python Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tuple r[0] which is of this format:

```
(OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'CCE__c'), ('url', 'aA1')])), ('VARIABLE1', '00AE'), ('Opportunity__r', OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Opportunity'), ('url', 'NyzIAE')])), ('VARIABLE2', 'uJeIAK')])), ('VARIABLE3', 'a05EA1'))
```

I'm trying to extract VARIABLE1 and VARIABLE2. When I use:

```
r[0]['VARIABLE1']
```

I'm able to extract correctly. However, when I use:

```
r[0]['VARIABLE2']
```

it's throwing an error. Could someone tell me how to correctly extract Variable 2?

Comment: Unless you copied the code in wrong, `r[0]` is a string, so technically speaking `['VARIABLE1']` shouldn't be working. As you haven't said what error you have, it could be that.

Comment: Apologies. r[0] is not a string, it's a tuple. Made the edit.

Comment: If you format your tuple to show the structure better, you'll see that `'VARIABLE1'` and `'VARIABLE2'` are not at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a small structural problem, to access the `VARIABLE2` key, you must first access the`Opportunity__r` key.

Use the method of your variable `items()`, to see all keys:

```
r = (OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'CCE__c'), ('url', 'aA1')])), ('VARIABLE1', '00AE'), ('Opportunity__r', OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Opportunity'), ('url', 'NyzIAE')])), ('VARIABLE2', 'uJeIAK')])), ('VARIABLE3', 'a05EA1')]), )
r[0].keys()
r[0]['Opportunity__r']['VARIABLE2']
```